# What is the fastest way to do a SIMD gather without AVX(2)?

Tags: x86, sse, simd, sse4

Assuming I have SSE to SSE4.1, but not AVX(2), what is the fastest way to load a packed memory layout like this (all 32-bit integers):

```
a0 b0 c0 d0 a1 b1 c1 d1 a2 b2 c2 d2 a3 b3 c3 d3
```

Into four vectors `a, b, c, d`?

```
a: {a0, a1, a2, a3}
b: {b0, b1, b2, b3}
c: {c0, c1, c2, c3}
d: {d0, d1, d2, d3}
```

I'm not sure whether this is relevant or not, but in my actual application I have 16 vectors and as such `a0` and `a1` are 16*4 bytes apart in memory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you need here is 4 loads followed by a 4x4 transpose:

```
#include "emmintrin.h"                       // SSE2

v0 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i *)&a[0]);       // v0 = a0 b0 c0 d0 
v1 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i *)&a[16]);      // v1 = a1 b1 c1 d1
v2 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i *)&a[32]);      // v2 = a2 b2 c2 d2
v3 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i *)&a[48]);      // v3 = a3 b3 c3 d3

// 4x4 transpose

w0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi32(v0, v1);             // w0 = a0 a1 b0 b1 
w1 = _mm_unpackhi_epi32(v0, v1);             // w1 = c0 c1 d0 d1 
w2 = _mm_unpacklo_epi32(v2, v3);             // w2 = a2 a3 b2 b3
w3 = _mm_unpackhi_epi32(v2, v3);             // w3 = c2 c3 d2 d3
v0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi64(w0, w2);             // v0 = a0 a1 a2 a3
v1 = _mm_unpackhi_epi64(w0, w2);             // v1 = b0 b1 b2 b3
v2 = _mm_unpacklo_epi64(w1, w3);             // v2 = c0 c1 c2 c3
v3 = _mm_unpackhi_epi64(w1, w3);             // v3 = d0 d1 d2 d3
```

Note: this is probably more efficient than using AVX2 gathered loads, since they generate a read cycle per element, which makes them really only useful when the access pattern is unknown or difficult to work with.

Comment: You may have missed the sentence in my question about having 16 vectors instead of 4. Should I use like 4 transposes?

Comment: Indeed - without knowing what you plan to do with all these vectors it's hard to give a complete solution, but yes, you can just repeat the above steps for the remaining 12 vectors, in groups of 4.